# Time Series forecast on Spark

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning, time-series, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-ml

So I´m trying to do power consumption forecast with time series data with Apache Spark. Sample of the data is :

```
03.01.15;22:30;236,25
03.01.15;22:15;240
04.01.15;16:00;243,775
```

and so on for two year. I have Observations every 15 minutes

What is the best way to predict the power consumption  ?

I try `LinearRegression`, `Decision trees` etc. I always get huge MSEs (788). 
I try pass months, days, hours, minutes as `OneHotEncoder`. I try to do a forecast only for weeks etc.

Means of the data `year`, `month`, `day`:

```
[2014.3996710526321,5.726973684210525,15.713815789473673]
```

Variance of the data `year`, `month`, `day`:

```
[0.2403293809070049,10.218579294199253,77.46326844706495]
```

Test Mean Squared Error

```
788.2397552290726
```

If I pass the values direct like `LabeledPoint(236.25, 2015.0,1.0,3.0,22.0,30.0))` the MSE goes up to `1280.8`. If I pass to the model only one observation per day being this the max value it does not help to.

But If I use `KNIME` and try the example for time series but with my data they do not take the dates and time in consideration, instead they lagged the power consumptions for each observation.

I see that Cloudera has a library for `Time Series` but I do not understand why do I need it.

Can someone describe the process of doing a good forecast on time series data ?  At the end I want to input a date and time and get a prediction.

Comment: Have you looked at arima and holt-winters?

Comment: Hey Sergei, can you elaborate a little more ?

Comment: @JorgeMachado jorge i also want to use the ARIMA model to forecast the things. Could you help me with the same if your problem is solved

Comment: Hi, So until now I have this update you need to pass the last seven days of usage for your actual usage. To predict the next days just pass the last day as a feature. I´m still trying but it does not work as I expected..

Answer (score 0):

I have multiple questions about your issue, but let me try to work with what you've given me.

**First, let's generalise the problem.**

You have data in the form `<timestamp>, <value>`. Given the data was collected every 15 minutes for 2 years, you have a sample size of (4 x 24 x 365 x 2) *70080* observations (rows)

And let's say you want to develop a regression model to predict its behaviour.

First things first, you need to partition your dataset into training and test sets. You develop a model using the training set and you test the model on the test set. I would suggest a 9:1 split.

**Q1. Is this the kind of approach you have taken?**

MSE is calculated using the predicted values against the actual values in the test set.

**Q2. You mention an MSE - I have no idea how this was calculated (only 3 data points provided) or the range of values you are working with. Can you please affirm how your error is calculated and what the minimization criteria is?**

If linear regression fails (cannot predict the movements succesfully), it may be the case that your model is too simple - try using an MLP or combine the regression model with a Bayesian model (as power consumption is a continuous function).